# Use of undeclared identifier ' IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresentationType'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4.2

Well this is kinda weird.

I'm using a method from Quartz.framework
'IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresenationType'

for some reason, after linking/adding Quarts.framework file into the project,
the compiler still doesn't see it...

what am I doing wrong here...

```
- (NSString *)imageRepresentationType
{
     return IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresentationType;
}
```

when I option click on the method name it returns a popup of the definition type and small summary of it's class. Yet, when I command click it doesn't return anything.. 
Command click should take me to it's header file..
Adding to this, when clicking on the instance it should also return an explaination of it's self and it does not...

I've confirmed that my framework file are linked and nothing...
what do you guys think? or have I overlooked something? silly of me  :o)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you `#import`ed `<Quartz/Quartz.h>` in either your .h or .m file?

Adding the `Quartz.framework` to your project and linking against it in your target is only part of the process.

You're getting the `Use of undeclared identifier IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresentationType` error because, based on everything that's been imported into the current file through headers, `IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresentationType` has not previously been defined. While we know `IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresentationType` is defined in the ImageKit.framework (a subframework of the Quartz umbrella framework), the compiler doesn't because, despite adding the framework to your project and linking against it, it hasn't been made aware of it, if you will.

Adding an `#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>` line to the top of your .m file should likely allow that constant to be used, and the file successfully compiled.

Comment: thanks for that...I some hoe was under the impression that importing QuartzCore, would have taken care of that..I guessed wrong..  Thanks again..